# Find node inside a XML and get parent note

Tags: php, xml

I've a XML from a variable like this, where "FatturaElettronicaBody" can be present more than 1 times:

```
$variable = '<Root>
<FatturaElettronicaBody>
        <DatiGenerali>
            <DatiGeneraliDocumento>
                <TipoDocumento>TD01</TipoDocumento>
                <Divisa>EUR</Divisa>
                <Data>2018-12-31</Data>
                <Numero>2140/18</Numero>
                <ImportoTotaleDocumento>1843.71</ImportoTotaleDocumento>
                <Causale>FATTURA DIFFERITA VENDITA</Causale>
            </DatiGeneraliDocumento>
            <Attachment>
              <Filename>Test-1.pdf</Filename>
              <Base64File>nfsofsedfmskd=.......</Base64File>
            </Attachment>
            <Attachment>
              <Filename>Test-2.pdf</Filename>
              <Base64File>nfsogfdgdfgdfsffsdgsmskd=.......</Base64File>
            </Attachment>
            ...
         </DatiGenerali>
</FatturaElettronicaBody>
<FatturaElettronicaBody>
        <DatiGenerali>
            <DatiGeneraliDocumento>
                <TipoDocumento>TD01</TipoDocumento>
                <Divisa>EUR</Divisa>
                <Data>2018-10-29</Data>
                <Numero>2094/18</Numero>
                <ImportoTotaleDocumento>500.43</ImportoTotaleDocumento>
                <Causale>FATTURA VENDITA</Causale>
            </DatiGeneraliDocumento>
            <Attachment>
              <Filename>Test-N.pdf</Filename>
              <Base64File>nfsogdhswvervsv.......</Base64File>
            </Attachment>
         </DatiGenerali>
</FatturaElettronicaBody>
...
</Root>
';
```

My goal is to search inside the XML for the node "Numero" and get the parent node "DatiGeneraliDocumento" to show info about item found.

For example i need to find Numero = "2094/18" and print all info inside its "DatiGeneraliDocumento" node. In this example case:

```
TipoDocumento = TD01
Divisa = EUR
Data = 2018-10-29
ImportoTotaleDocumento = 500.43
Causale = FATTURA VENDITA
```

Is there a function in PHP to do this without cycle all my $variable?

---

UPDATE: I've modified my first request to get also "Attachment" nodes:

For example i need to find Numero = "2094/18" and print all info inside its "DatiGeneraliDocumento" node and all "Attachment". In this example case:

```
TipoDocumento = TD01
Divisa = EUR
Data = 2018-10-29
ImportoTotaleDocumento = 500.43
Causale = FATTURA VENDITA

Filename = Test-1.pdf
Base64File = nfsofsedfmskd=

Filename = Test-2.pdf
Base64File = nfsogfdgdfgdfsffsdgsmskd=
```

I've tried with lo luck:

```
$numeroFattura = "2094/18";

foreach ($xml->xpath('//DatiGenerali[Numero = "' . $numeroFattura . '"]') as $x) {
  foreach($x as $v) {
    echo $v->getName() .'='. $v ."<br>\n";
  }
}

//  GET ATTACHMENT  <---this doesn't work

foreach ($xml->xpath('//FatturaElettronicaBody[Numero = "' . $numeroFattura . '"]') as $x) {
    foreach ($x->xpath('//Allegati') as $allegato) {
        var_dump($allegato);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i've pasted only a piece from full XML...i'll correct now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHPs [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to extract the information you want. By specifying the node value for `Numero` in the XPath query, we get only the node you are interested in:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($variable);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//DatiGeneraliDocumento[Numero='2094/18']");
foreach ($nodes as $nodelist) {
    foreach ($nodelist->childNodes as $node) {
        if ($node->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE) echo $node->nodeName . " = " . $node->nodeValue . "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
TipoDocumento = TD01 
Divisa = EUR 
Data = 2018-10-29 
Numero = 2094/18 
ImportoTotaleDocumento = 500.43 
Causale = FATTURA VENDITA
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Eg7VM)

Comment: Your example is working. If I use on my project I get error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @GiuseppeLodiRizzini try my new code, I've updated it so it should work on older PHP versions too.

Comment: @GiuseppeLodiRizzini I've simplified the code a little bit. See my edit.

Comment: firts and last code doesn't work for me. I get working for the second version provided by you. By i get another problem, like code of splash58. Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found. I think is my string XML a problem

Comment: @GiuseppeLodiRizzini I've rolled back my answer. You must be using a *very* old version of PHP. It sounds like your XML might have been through something like `htmlentities` to convert `<` to `&lt;`, you could try running it through [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to fix that

Comment: @nick I would suggest using `$node instanceof DOMElement` or `$node->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE` as the condition to validate that the node is an element. Text nodes are not the only nodes you want to ignore: https://3v4l.org/RqG1Q

Comment: @Nick my original XML was corrupt sorry. Now it's ok. But i've need to modify my question for attachment nodes also. :) can you help me?

Comment: @ThW thanks for that, I really appreciate the demo too - I learnt something new today. I've updated my answer with the code that works for the oldest versions.

Comment: @GiuseppeLodiRizzini I've made a slight change to my code based on some comments. It should still run fine for your example. Your update is quite big, it should really be a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Using simplexml

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($variable);
foreach ($xml->xpath('//DatiGeneraliDocumento[Numero = "2094/18"]') as $x) {
    foreach($x as $v) {
       echo $v->getName() .'='. $v ."<br>\n";
    }
}
```

[**demo**](https://3v4l.org/XsXFj)

Comment: Your code also works great. Only a problem but I think is on my XML string. I get error: Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found

Comment: Remove spaces before `<Root>`

Comment: my original XML was corrupt. code is working. thanks

Comment: I've modified my original request cause i've added a new node request child.